# Trying to understand the time complexity of a binary search

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, binary-search

I am trying to understand the Big O notation for the time complexity of a binary search. I understand it is O(log n). So is this basically saying that for a list of 16 elements, it will at maximum take log2(16) = 4 attempts? If that is true how would that work for a list of 12 where the log = 3.6?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usefulness of big-oh notation is ***not*** that it can tell precisely how many operations it will take to process an input of a certain size.  It can't.

Big-oh notation tells us how the number of operations required to do the processing ***varies in relation*** to the input size.

So, substituting actual numbers does not make much sense.

If it will really help you to understand it in terms of actual numbers, then you can think of them as being averages, so for a list of 12 elements you can think of binary search as requiring on the average 3.6 operations.

However, be advised that this is a rather narrow view of what big-oh notation is all about.  The real usefulness of big-oh notation lies in telling us that binary search is better than linear search, not in being able to tell us precisely how many operations a certain specific example will require.

Comment: Ah ok, so is it saying that the number of operations will increase logarithmically as the input size increases, and you dont worry about numbers?

Comment: Precisely.  The actual numbers are details, and so is the actual cost that an operation represents for the machine.  As far as the machine is concerned, one operation in binary search will actually take more clock cycles than one operation in linear search, because the algorithm is more complex.  But it does not matter, because as you keep examining larger and larger input sets, there will always be a point where binary search will start outperforming linear search, regardless of how inefficiently it performs each operation.  That's the beauty of big-Oh.

Comment: Also, I notice people downvoting your question.  So that you don't get disappointed, let me tell you that this is because posters are expected to do some research before posting a question, and the prevailing opinion is that everything about big-oh is pretty well documented and relatively easily accessible.  (See wikipedia.)  However, judging by other questions I see here every day, yours is not that bad.

Comment: Yeah, ok makes sense thanks dude, appreicate it. I did look at other questions, but I didn't see any with actual numbers so thats why I asked but now I see that the numbers arent actually important, it just describes it